Can I send a masstransit message with raw json format without envelope but not trigger every consumer?
I am using MassTransit for RabbitMQ functions with .net6.
I use the code below to send/subscribe the message.
But I found that when I publish the message in a consumer format from RabbitMQ management web.
All the consumer would be triggered instead only trigger the consumer that meet the payload format.
I know if I wrap the message in an envelope could solve the problem.
But for some reason I didn't want to use that format because that contain too many message I didn't want record.
Is there any other ways to solve this problem?
For example, using headers to differentiate which consumer should receive the message?

The log would be:
2024-08-27 11:47:50.3704 INFO  [ProductConsumer] Message received context: {"Message":{"Code":"_code","Name":"_name"}}  
2024-08-27 11:47:50.4210 INFO  [NameConsumer] Message received context: {"Message":{"Name":null}} 

Here are my code:
Program.cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<ProductConsumer>();
    x.AddConsumer<NameConsumer>();
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host($"myRabbitHost.com", 5672, "VHOST" , configurator =>
        {
            configurator.Username("_user");
            configurator.Password("_pwd");
        });
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("AUTO.QUEUENAME", e =>
        {
            e.UseRawJsonSerializer();
            e.ConfigureConsumer<ProductConsumer>(context);
            e.ConfigureConsumer<NameConsumer>(context);
        });

        cfg.DefaultContentType = new ContentType("application/json");
        cfg.UseRawJsonDeserializer();
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});

NameConsumer.cs
public class NameConsumer: IConsumer<NameMessage>
{
    private readonly ILogger<NameConsumer> _logger;
    public NameConsumer(ILogger<NameConsumer> logger)
    {
        _logger=logger;
    }
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<NameMessage> context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(" [NameConsumer] Message received context: {conetxt} ",JsonSerializer.Serialize(context));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public interface NameMessage 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}

ProductConsumer.cs
public class ProductConsumer: IConsumer<ProductMessage>
{
    private readonly ILogger<ProductConsumer> _logger;
    public ProductConsumer(ILogger<ProductConsumer> logger)
    {
        _logger=logger;
    }
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ProductMessage> context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(" [ProductConsumer] Message received context: {conetxt} ",JsonSerializer.Serialize(context));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public interface ProductMessage 
{ 
    public string Code { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}


There is a header for message type: MT-MessageType
It has a very specific format, which you can see if you produce a message using MassTransit with the raw JSON serializer. If you specify that header, MassTransit will know the message type when deserializing the message.
Your only other option is to avoid putting unrelated consumers on the same queue. Having multiple unrelated consumers on the same queue should generally be avoided, but makes sense in some scenarios. If you have multiple message types on a single queue, you should always include the message type header (or use the message envelope with the message type).

You could simply make a condition to check the header.
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<NameMessage> context)
    {
        if (context.Headers.TryGetHeader("ConsumerType", out var headerValue) && headerValue?.ToString() == "TypeA")
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(" [NameConsumer] Message received context: {conetxt} ", JsonSerializer.Serialize(context));
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

